# Using Couchbase Lite in android system service

Tags: android, couchbase, android-source, couchbase-lite

I am trying to customize the android framework. Can Anyone tell me whether it is possible to use Couchbase Lite in the system service or it can only be used in the app?

If it can be used in the system service, how do I do that? where should I add the couchbase library to?

Comment: Couchbase Lite can be used in any android code, but what exactly are you trying to build from source?

Comment: I am trying to modify the system service, use couchbase lite to store some data when the system service is invoked, instead of leaving it to the app developer to invoke the couchbase lite's methods in the app.

Comment: Okay. Sounds like an interesting problem. You just need a `Context` object to do that, right?

Comment: Yeah, I need an AndroidContext object to create a Manager right? and where should the couchbase library go if I want to add them to the android framework?

Comment: Into the `build.gradle` as a dependency if that service uses Gradle, I would imagine. Otherwise, you should be able to compile the necessary JAR files

Comment: And I meant `android.content.Context`, which is available because a `Service` extends that class. I didn't necessarily mean the Couchbase `AndroidContext` object, but I think they are linked together

Comment: can couchbase lite be compiled into a single Jar file like other libraries? and then where should it go if the jar file is meant to be used by system service?

Comment: I'm not entirely I understand what you mean by "system service". Which Android source project are you trying to rewrite? That would help me or someone else answer better

Comment: an example of android system service is the LocationManagerService, which provides the location updates to the app.

Comment: Do you need to integrate it to an existing service, or are you creating your own service?

Comment: I need to use it in a system service that I added